# Is it possible to use the std::nothrow argument for a placement new operation?

Tags: c++, new-operator

I have a use case where I want to use placement new but also want to ensure that the new operation won't throw.

I figure I'd want something like the below (note this doesn't compile) but I wasn't sure how exactly to do it.

```
char buf1[100];                                                                                                           
Foo* foo = new (std::nothrow) (buf1) Foo(100);
```

Comment: new would only throw if memory cannot be allocated. since you are using placement new it should not throw, but of course the ctor may throw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to use `std::nothrow` in a placement new expression.  unlike `new`/`new[]`, placement `new`/`new[]` are already defined as being `noexcept`.

[[new.delete.placement]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/new.delete.placement)

> ```
> [[nodiscard]] void* operator new(std::size_t size, void* ptr) noexcept;
> [[nodiscard]] void* operator new[](std::size_t size, void* ptr) noexcept;
> ```

If you look in [[new.delete.single]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/new.delete.single) and [[new.delete.array]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/new.delete.array) you'll see that the placement version will call the corresponding `std::nothrow` versions of `new`/`new[]`.